# python webbrowser.open() ignores BROWSER="safari"

Tags: python

I have the following script

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://python.org")
```

that I run with

```
BROWSER="safari" python myscript.py
```

This opens Google Chrome instead of safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [webbrowser module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) is not ignoring `BROWSER`, but specifying `BROWSER="safari"` is not correct. `BROWSER` should point to executables not browser names. Specifying `BROWSER="safari"` overwrites the default registration for `safari` which is [`MacOSXOSAScript("safari")`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9b66caf098608ae882342776b9da051a7d838731/Lib/webbrowser.py#L618-L654) and replaces it with [`GenericBrowser("safari")`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9b66caf098608ae882342776b9da051a7d838731/Lib/webbrowser.py#L159-L184) which will fail to open Safari.

The following script will show what happens to `webbrowser.get('safari')` when you run with and without `BROWSER="safari"`

```
import os
os.environ.pop('BROWSER', None)
import webbrowser

print("Without $BROWSER")
a = webbrowser.get('safari') # <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x100fc5370>
print(a)
print(webbrowser._browsers) # {'safari': <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x100fc5370>, ...}
print(webbrowser._tryorder)

print("With $BROWSER")
os.environ['BROWSER'] = 'safari'
webbrowser.register_standard_browsers()
b = webbrowser.get('safari') # <webbrowser.GenericBrowser object at 0x102ef2e10>
print(b)
print(webbrowser._browsers) # {'safari': <webbrowser.GenericBrowser object at 0x102ef2e10>, ...}
print(webbrowser._tryorder)
```

which outputs

```
Without $BROWSER
<webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x103f11400>
{'macosx': [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x103ee2690>], 'chrome': [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x103ee2660>], 'firefox': [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x103ee26f0>], 'safari': [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x103f11400>], 'gio': [None, <webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser object at 0x103f11820>]}
['MacOSX', 'chrome', 'firefox', 'safari', 'gio']
With $BROWSER
<webbrowser.GenericBrowser object at 0x103ee26f0>
{'macosx': [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x103fcef30>], 'chrome': [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x103fcef90>], 'firefox': [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x103ee2690>], 'safari': [None, <webbrowser.GenericBrowser object at 0x103ee26f0>], 'gio': [None, <webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser object at 0x104099220>]}
['safari', 'MacOSX', 'chrome', 'firefox', 'safari', 'gio']
```

As you may have notice after settings `BROWSER="safari"` then `safari` is no longer a `MacOSXOSAScript("safari")` but a `GenericBrowser()` and that's the problem.

the webbrowser module reads the `BROWSER` environment variable in [webbrowser.register_standard_browsers()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b1f8398d0ffe3c8ba2cca79d0c0f19a6a34e72a/Lib/webbrowser.py#L535-L545) which is called automatically.  And that assumes that you pass paths to executables in `BROWSER` **NOT** browser names (like `safari`, `firefox`, `chrome` , `google-chrome`, etc)